# Difference between two ways of injecting modules in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What's the difference between these two ways of loading modules in AngularJS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

// VERSION 1

app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$dep1', '$dep2', function($scope, $dep1, $dep2) {
    // controller code
}];

// VERSION 2

function HomeCtrl($scope, $dep1, $dep2){
    // controller code
}
HomeCtrl.$inject=['$scope', '$dep1', '$dep2'];
return HomeCtrl;

// Then load in the controller into the app module
app.controller('HomeCtrl', HomeCtrl);
```

Comment: The first one is minification safe. You can concatenate your script and it will still work. This is because the names of your injected services won't be cut. The second one is a slightly more verbose way of doing this.

Comment: @DonaldSupertramp Both are minification safe

Comment: @WayneEllery that's why I wrote: "The second one is a slightly more verbose way of doing this"

Answer (score 2):

Both ways are for minification safe dependency injection. Here is an abstract from source code, [injector.js file](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/auto/injector.js#L88):

```
if (typeof fn === 'function') {
    if (!($inject = fn.$inject)) {
        $inject = [];

        // convert function to string, parse arguments

        fn.$inject = $inject;
    }
} else if (isArray(fn)) {
    last = fn.length - 1;
    assertArgFn(fn[last], 'fn');
    $inject = fn.slice(0, last);
} else {
    assertArgFn(fn, 'fn', true);
}
return $inject;
```

Above code explains very well that if function you are injecting dependencies into, has type of

1. **function**

Angular checks if this functio has property `$inject` and if so here is resulting array of services to inject.

2. **array**

Angular takes values from this array leaving out the last element, which is supposed to be an actual function to inject value into.

Note the part I denoted as comment `// convert function to string, parse arguments`. In case if there is no `$inject` property is configured and provided controller/service/etc. is actually of a function type, then Angular will take string representation of the function and parse literally defined parameters it accepts. Then obtained array of parameters will be used as services to inject.

So as you can see the difference is very minor.

Comment: Sorry I'm still unclear what the difference between the two is. The reason I ask is because I want to wrap the modules inside requirejs e.g. `define([], function() { // code });` and I'm seen version 2 used when used inside requirejs rather than version 1 (the usual seen on Angular Docs).

Comment: You can use the one you like more, they both yield the same result.