# Difference between dependency injection syntaxes in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

AngularJS supports two slightly different syntaxes for **dependency injection**

**Syntax 1**

```
myModule.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, myService) {
    ...
    ...
});
```

**Syntax 2**

```
myModule.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'myService', function($scope, $http, myService) {
    ...
    ...
}]);
```

Is there a fundamental difference between the two syntaxes?
When to use either of the two syntaxes?

Comment: this has been asked many times and is explained in the documentation

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410706/difference-between-two-ways-of-injecting-modules-in-angular/28410903#28410903) answer.

Comment: DI Docs https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: Syntax 2 is used for minification. Strings are not modified by minifiers so they are used for mapping the corresponding minified function parameters (injections) so they point back to the correct services.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax 2 is called **type hinting**, if you plan to uglify and mangle your code, angular would still know what services to inject.

After mangling and ugilying:

```
myModule.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'myService', function(a, b, c) {
```

Angular would read the string values of the array provided in order to determine the name of the services `a, b, c` in order to inject them properly.